# How to join two dataframes where IDs do not match and create new column to represent what dataframe ID came from?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes like this

df1:

```
id    column1    column2 
1      30          90
2      1            2
```

df2:

```
id    column1    column2 
1      30          90
3      1            2
```

I want to create logic that merges these two dataframes where IDs do not match (column names are the same) and then I want to create a new column that states what dataframe the ID came from. How would I do this?

Final merged df:

```
id    column1    column2    df_name
2      30          90         df1
3      1            2         df2
```

edit:

could final df pull in all columns from both dataframes?

```
 id    column1.df1    column2.df1   column1.df2    column2.df2     df_name
    2      30          90                 30            90           df1
    3      1            2                  1             2           df2
```

Comment: Why does `id` in final merged `df` change?

Comment: Not quit clear for the question here, in final merge df  where is id 2 come from ?

Comment: @user3471881 the id changes in final_merged_df because I only want IDs that are different in both dataframes. Does that help

Comment: @W-B the 2 comes from df1. I only want a dataframe where IDs are not the same between both dataframes

Comment: @RustyShackleford  just adding my solution . also your update is just duplicated the column twice , you sure you still want them , since it will eating up the memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) DataFrames together:

```
df = (pd.concat([df1, df2],  keys=('df1','df2'))
        .rename_axis(('df_name','idx'))
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .reset_index())

print (df)
  df_name  id  column1  column2
0     df1   1       30       90
1     df1   2        1        2
2     df2   1       30       90
3     df2   3        1        2
```

Then get all same `id`:

```
a = df1.merge(df2, on='id')['id']
```

And last filter by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df = df[~df['id'].isin(a)]
print (df)
  df_name  id  column1  column2
1     df1   2        1        2
3     df2   3        1        2
```

EDIT:

Similar solution like @W-B, only added parameter `id` and `suffixes`:

```
df = (df1.merge(df2,indicator=True,how='outer', on='id', suffixes=('_df1','_df2'))
         .query("_merge != 'both'"))
df['_merge'] = df['_merge'].map({'left_only':'df1','right_only':'df2'})

print (df)
   id  column1_df1  column2_df1  column1_df2  column2_df2 _merge
1   2          1.0          2.0          NaN          NaN    df1
2   3          NaN          NaN          1.0          2.0    df2
```

If want all rows, also rows with same `id`:

```
df['_merge'] = df['_merge'].map({'left_only':'df1','right_only':'df2', 'both':'df1+df2'})

print (df)
   id  column1_df1  column2_df1  column1_df2  column2_df2   _merge
0   1         30.0         90.0         30.0         90.0  df1+df2
1   2          1.0          2.0          NaN          NaN      df1
2   3          NaN          NaN          1.0          2.0      df2
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for! Could I pull in the columns from both dataframes even though they have the same names?

Comment: Nice edit then , But I still not recommend op include the duplicate column ...:-)

Answer (score 2):

Let us do with `merge`

```
df=df1.merge(df2,indicator = True,how='outer').loc[lambda x : x['_merge'].ne('both')]
df['df_name']=df['_merge'].map({'left_only':'df1','right_only':'df2'})
df
Out[328]: 
   id  column1  column2      _merge df_name
1   2        1        2   left_only     df1
2   3        1        2  right_only     df2
```